# How to extend(inherit) a global CSS class from within a styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Is it possible to inject a global CSS class into a [`styled-component`](https://www.styled-components.com/)?

Similar to extending in LESS using `&:extend` or `@extend` in SASS.

This code doesnt apply the `globalCSS` styles:

```
const extendedComponent = styled.div`
  &:extend(.globalClass) // I want this component to inherit all styles of .globalaCSS
  .otherStyles {
    ...
  }
`
```

The globalClass does exits and even applies styles when used inline:

```
extendedComponent(className="globalCSS)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just add the "class name" to your element,
but if you really want to inherit or extend.

Use their example as reference:

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

// We're extending Button with some extra styles
const TomatoButton = Button.extend`
  color: tomato;
  border-color: tomato;
`;
```

docs link:
https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the issue? I just came across this same question. I am new to styled components. In Bootstrap, you can use spacing type classes like "mt-2", which means "margin top 2 units of spacing".  These units of spacing vary based on media queries, or even your own sass variable modifications.  You can create a class in sass and do something like ".new-class { @extend .mt-2 : ... my stuff ... }. I think this is what the person was asking about?

Answer (score 2):

Use `attrs`: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs

```js
const extendedComponent = styled.div.attrs({
    className: 'globalCssClassThatIWantToExtend'
})`
    .otherStyles {
        /*...*/
    }
`;
```

The `attrs` function can also accept a props function:

```js
.attrs(props => ({
    /*...*/
}))
```